# Power of two to get an integer

Tags: algorithm, integer, exponentiation

I need a (fairly) fast way to get the following for my code.
Background: I have to work with powers of numbers and their product, so I decided to use logs.
Now I need a way to convert the log back to an integer.

I can't just take 2^log_val (I'm working with log base 2) because the answer will be too large. In fact i need to give the answer mod M for given M.

I tried doing this. I wrote log_val as p+q, where q is a float, q < 1 and p is an integer.
Now i can calculate 2^p very fast using log n exponentiation along with the modulo, but i can't do anything with the 2^q. What I thought of doing is finding the first integral power of 2, say x, such that 2^(x+q) is very close to an integer, and then calculate 2^p-x.

This is too long for me because in the worst case I'll take O(p) steps.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Is M fixed? Depending on how much memory you've got and the accuracy you need, you can store the rounded `2^q` values in a pre-calculated table.

Comment: No actually, I have many different M's. 
And q is a float

Comment: Floats are still 32 bit values when all's said and done, so they can be used as indexes into a lookup table. But also, depending on the accuracy required, you can store `p+q` as a 64 bit fixed point number with 32 bits of fraction part and 32 bits of integer part.

Comment: Even better, once you do that, you can try the [right-to-left binary method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) explained here.

Comment: A lookup table of the sort will be very costly, O(10^9). I need this for a online judge where O(10^9) solution will time out

Comment: What's the original problem you're trying to some? Maybe logs were not a step in the right direction.

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/NOV14/problems/POWERMUL/

Comment: @KarlWistenn Take a look at the link I posted in a previous comment. You don't need logarithms or anything really, just a good method to calculate `n^n mod m` and then you can sum the results modulo m.

Comment: Yes, I know this, the fast exponentiation I mentioned was this. First, sum? You mean product?
And there are a lot of queries and test cases

Comment: @KarlWistenn Sorry, product, yes.

Comment: The thing is I need to divide f(N) by f(r) and f(N-r) [in the link].
And also for given N, M, there are 10^5 queries of the sort.
It has to be fast enough

Comment: @KarlWistenn First of all, when you calculate `f(N) mod M`, you will also implicitly calculate `f(N-1), f(N-2)...f(1) (all mod M)`. You won't throw these results away but keep them. Secondly, because `M` isn't too big, you can quickly factorise it. From that, calculating Euler's totient function for `M` is also possible. Once you have `φ(M)`, you can calculate the multiplicative inverse of any number, making modulo M division simple.

Comment: Yes, yes I know. But there can be many different Ms, right? Are you saying do this for each m? 
Will that be fast enough?
Since M <= 10^9.
Yes I know that about the totient function and modulo inverse. The problem is efficiency here.

Comment: Each test case will have only one `M` though with many different `r`s. And I don't know if it will be fast enough but it will certainly be faster than floating point.

Comment: What would be the best way to find the totient function for M?

Answer (score 2):

While working with large numbers as logs is usually a good approach, it won't work here. The issue is that working in log space throws away the least significant digits, thus you have lost information, and won't be able to go back. Working in mod space will also throw away information (otherwise your number gets to big, as you say), but it throws away the most significant ones instead.

For your particular problem `POWERMUL`, what I would do is to calculate the prime factorizations of the numbers from `1` to `N`. You have to be careful how you do it, since your `N` is fairly large.

Now, if your number is `k` with the prime factorization `{2: 3, 5: 2}` you get the factorization of `k^m` by `{2: m*3, 5:m*2}`. Division similarly turns into subtraction.

Once you have the prime factorization representation of `f(N)/(f(r)*f(N-r))` you can recreate the integer with a combination of modular multiplication and exponentiation. The later is a cool technique to look up. (In fact languages like python has it built in with `pow(3, 16, 7)=4`.

Have fun :)

Comment: What is the best way to prime factorize n numbers?
There are about 10^4 primes till 10^5

Comment: Using sieve of eratosthenes is usually fastest. However, thinking more about your problem, you may be able to come up with a faster way. Thinking in terms of 'how many factors of two are there in 2^2*4^4*6^6...' etc.

Comment: Yes, but still thats 10^5*10^4 primes = O(10^9) steps

Comment: Using the technique of my previous comment, you don't get the factor of `10^5`. In constant time (with pen and paper) I calculated that 2 divides '1^1*2^2*3^3*...*(10^5)^(10^5)' 5000265024 times. (Well actually logN time).

Comment: Yes but i need how many times every other prime divides it as well, and the 10^5 comes from the fact the query requires '1^1*2^2*3^3*...*r^r for all r < N.

Comment: I see. So you'll either have to exploit that there are only 65 primes less than `sqrt(10^5)`; or you can use the chinese remainder theorem and only calculate `f` modulo a few different primes. However the later method requires you to factorize `M` which takes around `sqrt(M)=10^4.5` time, so if `T` is very big, you can still run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an answer *mod N*, you can often do each step of your whole calculation *mod N*.  That way, you never exceed your system's integer size restrictions.

Comment: No I need mod M. And yes I do that, but how will I take a number to a real power modulo M?

Comment: Yes, exactly: how will you do _modular exponentiation_? :-)

Comment: Modular exponentiation of an integer to an integer is easy, but an integer to a float?

Comment: The trouble is not the exponentiation, but the division.